# Can't CD to a directory that exists

Tags: command-line, bash

So I'm trying to `gpg -c` a file, but it's deep in the nooks and crannies of my Documents folder. As per usual, you would have to `cd` into said folder that the file is in.

...that's not working here, as you told by now. For some reason, I can't get into a subdirectory of my Documents folder, amptly named, since I used to save everything over to Documents on Windows before I switched, "Pictures n shit". Upon attempting to use `cd "~/Documents/Pictures n shit/"`, the bash returns `bash: cd: ~/Documents/Pictures n shit/: No such file or directory`, which I know for a fact is wrong.

I tried looking it up here and elsewhere and found nothing. Is there a particular reason this is happening, or do I just have to move the file I want `gpg` to encrypt into a different folder for now?

Comment: Oh wait, please try `cd ~/"Documents/Pictures n shit"`… What happens if you enter `cd ~/Documents/Pictures` and press `Tab ↹` once? It should auto-complete the directory and take care of proper quoting for you. If nothing happens, hit `Tab ↹` a second time, then you’ll get a list of matching directories.

Comment: ...okay so I'm an absolute idiot and didn't know that bash did this.

The spaces were borking it; hitting tab gave `cd ~/Documents/Pictures\ n\ shit/`. Good to know I'll need that for later. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome! That’s a solution, but the actual issue is explained in the duplicate I marked. Have an upvote! :)